# How to advertise my unpublished work in my CV for graduate admissions, when I can't put it on arXiv?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, mathematics, arxiv, grey-literature

I am applying to graduate programs. I have an unpublished work. It has been submitted to the arXiv, but it has been put on hold. Also, we have submitted to a journal. I want to advertise my work on my CV.

What should I do ?

Comment: When do you have to submit your application? Can't you wait a  little longer to find out what's going on with the arXiv submission, then just list that in your CV when you have that straightened out?

Comment: Personal website?

Comment: @ff524 The deadline is on 20th December.

Comment: I sometimes add a paragraph on recent projects in my CV and I list titles and my contribution on them, in summary.

Answer (score 3):

If you have not already submitted applications, it's good to add a link to your personal website on your CV.

Your personal website is a good place to provide up-to-date information on what exactly you're working on currently.  As soon as you submit to arXiv, you can link to the work online.  Ultimately, you can update your website to include where it gets published.

Your personal website doesn't have to be super fancy, too.  It can just be plain HTML, meant to convey additional information to whoever may be reviewing your CV.